# Set line spacing to 1.15 in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, cpu-word, line-spacing

In Markdown, after a heading, my knitted document will revert to 1.0 line spacing even though I want it as 1.15. If I add a space after a header (with `<br>`), the 1.15 spacing is maintained. If I don't add the `<br>`, everything that follows is 1.0 spacing.

Is there a method in Markdown to encapsulate text within line spacing of 1.15?

Here are my YAML headers:

```yaml
title: "BLABLABLA:"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: P:/BLABLA/Template_Original.docx
  pdf_document: default
  officedown: default
params:
  program: Medical Program 1
```

Here is an example part of how the Markdown is currently set up:

```markdown
## `r params$program` Program Supplementary Report
<br>
<p>This document details the findings of the `r params$program` Program.<p>
```